# Am I Setting up this Hash Table Correctly?

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am in a data structures class and we are given a project regarding hash tables. An excerpt of the instructions I've been given are:

> The hash table is an array of pointers to struct `hash_table_entry`
>   all initialized to `Nil`.

So this is what I have written (again, an excerpt of the overall program):

```
hash_table_entry *hash_table = new hash_table_entry[hash_table_size];
for (int i=0;i<hash_table_size;i++)
{
    hash_table[i] = new hash_table_entry;
}
```

hash_table_entry is:

```
struct hash_table_entry{
char event_id; // Event id -- key used to hash on
int year; // Year of storm event
int event_index; // For the given year, the index into array of storm events };
```

So the questions I have are:

1. `hash_table` is an array of type `hash_table_entry` pointer, correct?
2. When the for loop runs through the array and creates a new `hash_table_entry` struct, are the default struct variables automatically set to "`Nil`"?

Thank you in advance for any insight!

Comment: If you are using C++ (apparent from the use of `new`), you should be using `std::vector` instead of manual dynamic memory allocation with `new`. There is no value `Nil` in C++. Do you mean `NULL` or `nullptr`? You have not shown the definition of `hash_table_entry`, so the question of how it is initialized by `new hash_table_entry;` cannot be answered. And `hash_table` is an array of `hash_table_entry`, not `hash_table_entry*` (pointer to `hash_table_entry`).

Comment: @uneven_mark I would love to use vectors but unfortunatley the guidelines of the project are that we can only use iostream, string, and fstream libraries. I must mean NULL if there is no NIL in C++, honestly I have never heard of NIL before this assignment. I've edited the original question to include the definition of 'hash_table_entry'

Comment: 1. No it's not; 2. This won't even compile, as you should've discovered by yourself, if you actually tried to compile the shown code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the insight. I'm writing this in Notepad++ and compiling with a makefile over SSH so there's no compiler check in my local environment. How do I make 'hash_table' an array of 'hash_table_entry' pointers?

Comment: @rclever2 Are you saying that you are unable to compile and run your code whenever you want while writing it? That is not a feasible way to program. Install whatever C++ compiler on you machine (GCC, Clang, MinGW, etc.) and IDE and use it to regularly recompile and test after code changes. Even something like using https://www.godbolt.org is better than not being able to compile your code at all.

Comment: You have much more issues to worry about. Your current development plan is completely unworkable. Instead, you need to focus on putting together a real development environment, if you wish to be productive. This piecemeal approach simply will not work. In order to be able to develop in C++, the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, you simply canot write some code over on one machine, then copy it to another one, try to compile, and when it doesn't, try to figure it out, and then go back to the first machine and make changes. You need to think of a better way.

Comment: @uneven_mark I have MinGW installed on my machine but the program needs to run with command line arguments on a linux system, so I can only test my code on a university linux system that I can SSH into.

Comment: Then simply edit your code on the university's system, using vi or emacs. I happen to be making a living doing exactly that, editing my code in emacs over a tunneled ssh connection, and building the code straight from emacs. You need to learn how to use Linux, if you're serious about learning C++ on a Linux box. Hobbling yourself by editing the code in notepad on a windows box, and then copying over the files, is just making things much more cumbersome then they need to be.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes I understand it's an incredibly inefficient way to code but my professor advised us to test only on a linux environment since that is the environment the project will be graded in. Edit: I find it's quicker to type in a GUI based text editor and SSH the file over than work my way around a vi editor

Comment: Nobody said you cannot test there.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What do you recommend I do then? I don't want to use a vi editor that I can't use my cursor to navigate the code, that would take me exponentially longer to do than to just SSH a .cpp file I'm editing on Notepad++

Comment: I use vi occasionally. I have no problems with using cursor keys for navigation. I don't know what is your difficulty is. Editing and compiling code on Linux is not difficult, and will be much more efficient then constantly copying files back and forth. That's my recommendation: invest some time, up front, setting up a more productive development environment. The productivity gains will make up for this up-front investment very quickly, and you can immediately edit, compile, run, and debug your code, in a debugger, right on Linux.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Cursor as in mouse cursor, that should have been obvious. The reality is that using a mouse and scroll wheel is just faster than using arrow keys to navigate a several hundred line program

Comment: I just took some quick stats: my current C++ project has about 250000 lines of code. The largest .C source file has about 4000 lines. I don't remember the last time I used a mouse to scroll any part of this. PgUp/PgDn is quite efficient. Especially in emacs' split-screen view, showing multiple parts of the same file simultaneously. Jump over several thousand lines of code, precisely, in a fraction of a second, 4 keypresses. This is what someone who does C++ for a living does. Try doing that with your mouse, and notepad. P.S. I edit and build the whole thing over a tunneled ssh connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hash_table is an array of type hash_table_entry pointer, correct?

No, `hash_table` is a *pointer to `hash_table_entry`*, which after the given initialization with `new hash_table_entry[hash_table_size];` will point to (the first element of) an *array of `hash_table_entry`* (not *array to pointer to `hash_table_entry`*).

> When the for loop runs through the array and creates a new hash_table_entry struct, are the default struct variables automatically set to "Nil"?

As noted in the comments, the assignment

```
hash_table[i] = new hash_table_entry;
```

doesn't compile, because of a type mismatch. `hash_table[i]` has type `hash_table_entry`, while `new hash_table_entry` has type `hash_table_entry*`.

But that aside, for the question of initialization: `new hash_table_entry` and `new hash_table_entry[hash_table_size]` (both creating objects or arrays of objects of type `hash_table_entry`) create objects. Because there is no initializer given in these expressions, the objects are default-constructed. Because `hash_table_entry` does not have any user-declared/defined constructors, this means that the implicitly defined default constructor will be used. This constructor does perform default-constuction of all members of `hash_table_entry`, which (because they are non-class types) means that nothing is done with them and therefore the members' values will remain *indeterminate* after the initialization.

Whether this is what the assignment means with `Nil` is doubtful. `Nil` is not something that exists in C++ and so I assume that `NULL` or `nullptr` is meant and that you are supposed to allocate an array of pointers instead of objects and initialize them with null pointers.

An array of pointers to `hash_table_entry` is allocated with `new hash_table_entry*[hash_table_size]` which results in a `hash_table_entry**`, not `hash_table_entry*`. If you add `{}` as in:

```
new hash_table_entry*[hash_table_size]{}
```

or more explicitly

```
new hash_table_entry*[hash_table_size]{nullptr}
```

it will also initialize all of the pointers to null pointers for you, no loop needed.